# bad interpreter no such file or directory /usr/bin/python

Tags: python

I created script python and I moved it to /usr/bin and I named the script by sdfgdgh without .py and I write in script this code

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print("worked")
```

and I was given the script chmod +x
but when I type in terminal sdfgdgh give me the error :

> bad interpreter no such file or directory /usr/bin/python

why and what is the solution ?

Comment: What is the output of `which python` and `ls /usr/bin/python`?

Comment: Are you sure you have python installed on your system? If so what where do you have it installed ?

Comment: Seems like the operating system is not recognizing the location of Python. You have not added python to your PATH in your .bashrc file.

Comment: @karthikbharadwaj There is no need to add anything in .bashrc since python interpreter is defined here as `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @karthikbharadwaj: It's not true. adding python to PATH won't help in this case as in his script explicitly calls `/usr/bin/python` So if python is located in any other place it will not work,

Comment: yes i'm sure my python in /usr/bin and my python file i created it in /usr/bin

Comment: What happens if you try to execute python with the absolut path `/usr/bin/python` on the command line? Does it work?

Comment: so if didn't so i can't add my python file in directory python path ok i understood  thanks you

Comment: @vb.net No, you do not need to add your python file in /usr/bin. Is `/usr/bin/python /path/to/sdfgdgh` working ?

Comment: You should also check the encoding of the source file.
If it is UTF-8 with BOM the sequence "#!" will not work.

Answer (score 29):

The problem is with your python installation. Probably your `/usr/bin/python` either does not exist at all or it is a dead symbolic link pointing to non-existing python.

So first solution is to check if `/usr/bin/python` exists. If so check if it's not dead link and if it is, fix the link to point to existing python intepretter:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -fs <full_path_to_existing_python_binary> python
```

If you can't or don't want to change `/usr/bin/python` but you have python installed and its location is recognized by the system (i.e. calling `python` from shell works) you can try changing your script as a workaround:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
print("worked")
```

This way your script will use python as an interpreter regardless of the real python location as long as it is in your PATH.

Comment: i find the solution now i copied my script to /bin and now work may be don't work if was in like path of the interpreter , thank you all for help me

Comment: sudo ln -fs /s/miniconda2/bin/python python and it worked

Comment: Worked on default Mac python installation using `#! /usr/bin/env python3`. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

1. First check which python you've installed with

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

2. Then check if it's executable

```
python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

3. If you run a py file with dos format on linux you also will get this issue.

Method a:
check dos fileformat with `cat -v filepath` to see if the line end with `^M`.

Method b:
`vim filepath` -> :set ff to check it, for example "eni.py" [dos] 64L, 2151C

Method c:
`file filepath` to check if it has `CRLF`
file_path: Python script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable, with CRLF line terminators

Solution:
you can set the filefort to unix with `vim filepath` then `:set ff unix`

Comment: There is a nice utility, **dos2unix**, that you can install which converts the file from dos to unix format.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problems, I had installed a package in my Ubuntu 20.04 which depended on Python 2. This messed up the meaning of `python`. I had to uninstall that package: `qjoypad`, `xboxdrv` and one other; uninstall python 2 with `sudo apt remove python`.

Then to confirm, I used `which python` which gave a blank output. The next step was to `cd /usr/bin` and then create a symlink with `sudo ln -fs python3 python`.

Comment: I tried this, but on montery it gives me `ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 4):

You can install python with:

```sh
apt install python
```

After that, the `python` command will work.

Answer (score 4):

A flexible solution would be to point at this address using the address of an arbitrary python version.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu, you can find the installed Python versions with

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python
```

For me this printed:

```
dh_python2
python
python2
python2.7
python3
python3.8
python3.8-config
python3-config
python3-futurize
python3-pasteurize
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config#
```

Now let's say you want to point to python 3.8. The following line of code presents python3.8 as the 1st alternative(Hence the 1 at the end).

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 1
```

Now whenever the `python` is referred, instead of the `/usr/bin/python` folder, `/usr/bin/python3.8` will be accessed.

You can enlist other alternatives too. To see which alternatives you have, use

```
update-alternatives --list python
```

Finally to switch between those alternatives, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same problem. Maybe you are editing the script on windows as a file and executing it on Linux. below steps resolved the problem for me:

1. edit on terminal-> sudo vi myscript.py
2. add python location-> #!/location/anaconda/bin/python

From the ^M you can see that the file myscript.py is using windows/dos-style line breaks not Linux style

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is late but, I believe it can be of help to someone.

First: Check which python version you are using. `which python3`
Second: This will print the exact path for you. `/usr/bin/python3`
Third: Copy the path and use in your script. `#! /usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I ran `virtualenv ven3` twice by mistake, as it corrupted the ven3 directory.

Answer (score -1):

Simply run this :-

```sh
sudo bash -c "test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -qqy update && apt install -qy python-minimal)
```

Comment: A direct solution is welcome, but please ensure you add context around it so your fellow users will understand how it solves the problem

Comment: This gives me /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found