# The file specified the interpreter is not an executable command

Tags: python, terminal, pip

I am trying to run a flask app with python. When I tried to `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I get the following error

```
   Failed to execute process '/Users/Kantemirovs/asdf/venv/bin/pip'. Reason:
The file '/Users/Kantemirovs/asdf/venv/bin/pip' specified the interpreter '/Users/Kantemirovs/asdf/venv/bin/python3', which is not an executable command.
```

Can somebody help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Check if `/Users/Kantemirovs/asdf/venv/bin/python3` even exists. In case it does but is a symlink, check whether the path it points to exists. Things like this often happen when you upgrade your system Python e.g. from 3.8 to 3.9, but symlinks in virtualenvs keep pointing to the 3.8 executable, which no longer exists. In that case the easiest solution is usually to just recreate the virtualenv from scratch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bad interpreter no such file or directory /usr/bin/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822600/bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-bin-python)

Answer (score 2):

try `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`