# getting error when i try to run command in ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

when i am trying to run command, `$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` i am getting this error

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

i just updated to ubuntu 22 version, even apt-get fix broken install command is not working every time i am getting python3 dependencies error, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated, i am trying to fix this issue last 2 days but not able to resolve it

Comment: Maybe you didn't have python3 installed in your machine. Just install one,

Comment: try a `wihich python3` or a `which python` to see where you're good _Python_ install, if you have one, is. What does a `python --version` or a `python3 --version` executed from a command line say, btw?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. There's probably more ubuntu expertise at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bad interpreter no such file or directory /usr/bin/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822600/bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-bin-python)

Comment: when i try to run command apt fix broken install i am getting error of py3compile not found and when i am running this command to install sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal i am getting error apt --fix-broken install so i am not able to do anything